# Adding textView to actual Activity without opening a new Activity

Tags: android, onclick, textview, setcontentview

I've started with Android programming yesterday and I worked a bit through the online tutorial, and I have one question:

I have put an icon into my blank View and it is calling my `showText` method when you click on it, which will to the following:

```
 /* Called when the user clicks the android button */**

    public void showText(View view) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        textView.setText("Hurray! I'm an android!");
        setContentView(textView);
}
```

Of course I could start a new Intent and pass it over a complete new Activity like a `showTextActivity` or something like that, but I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to display this text to the current view, where my icon is shown.

When I change the `ContentView` with `setContentView(textView)` my icon (a little android figure) disappears.

Is there something like an `add-method`, which adds that `textView` to my `main.xml` so that the layout changes and a matching `refresh-method` to make both my android figure and the text visible to me?

Comment: There's the `addContentView()` method.

Comment: @nobalG There are two `setContentView()` overloads that take `View` parameters.

Comment: @MikeM. :) thanks for pointing out,I was not aware of this; but where do we need the **setContentView()** specified by you?...in some frame or ???

Comment: @nobalG I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but if you want to dynamically create `View`s for the `Activity`'s layout, instead of using a static xml definition, that's what you'd use.

Comment: Thanks guys, the addContentView works fine. I don't understand what you meant with the fact, that there are two setContentView methods nobalG, but it works fine now. I also found something in that thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718900/android-adding-a-content-view

Does some of you know what the second parameter means?

Comment: The second parameter is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, which describes how the View you're adding is to be laid out the Activity's root layout. The base params are width and height, and each subclass will have special params to define behavior in a certain kind of Layout. [The docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add TextView to layout with Visibility parameter set to Hidden or Gone - when visibility is gone Control does not reserve space inside parent. Second thing is to refer parent container for example let say you have linear layout called mainContainer you can do :
    `LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainContainer);
ll.AddChild(textView)`

 That way you can create and manipulate your UI programatically but be care full its harder to reference such controlls and mantain thier state
**Edit:**
Also to set parameters for dynamically created Views you will need to refer appropriate LayoutParam class. If container for your controls is LinearLayout you will need to apply LinearLayoutParams etc. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This is MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout layout;
    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        TextView tv=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                        tv.setLayoutParams(lparams);

                        tv.setText("test");
                        layout.addView(tv);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my activity_main.xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```